# how do I import styles in a next js page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, next.js

I have a `styles` folder in my app and it contains a file named `Home.module.css`.

But whenever I add this code in my `pages/index.js`, i get an error,
the error is always the same, 404 page not found..

```
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
```

Please help me get out of this problem.

Comment: Can you share your folder structure?

Comment: A 404 error would most likely not be related to how you're importing your styles. Can you please add the full error message/stack?

Answer (score 0):

Following [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support) you should just import styles without naming it:

```js
import '.../styles/Home.module.css'
```

But, if you want to use varibales you can [install SASS](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#sass-variables) and import your styles by name:

```js
import variables from '../styles/variables.module.scss'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout color={variables.primaryColor}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

NOTE: pay attention to extension. If you are using **SASS** the extension of file should be **SCSS**.

Answer (score 0):

import "../styles/Home.module.css";   Is the Best way to do it without error as @Morani answered

The course materials usually have the import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'  format, which doesn't work in any instance.  IF it does they should mention it in the course.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).